# How do I create a sword that can only break cobwebs in Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to give myself a sword that can only break cobwebs in Minecraft (Xbox One Bedrock Edition). It isn't working and I don't know why.

I've tried other people's answers on another question, but they don't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm very surprised that this question does not appear to be a duplicate.

Comment: Hi Alightminer8, welcome to Arqade! Can you include the code that you're trying to use but doesn't work? We can tell you if you're on the right track, or if you might need to look at it from a different angle.

Comment: ^What Gigazelle said, and also if you can, link us to the answers you mention that you've tried so we know not to suggest stuff you've already considered :)

Comment: Why did 4 people vote to close this as "unclear"? It's very clear and even the solution is clear and simple (which is why I'm also surprised about the upvotes), simply the `CanBreak` tag, with whatever syntax MCPE uses (can be looked up in the wiki). Can people please remove their close votes so that I can vote it as a duplicate? If I do that now, it will be hidden for some reason.